# Cucumber .feature file not picking up Step Definition in Java class

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, feature-file

I am writing some cucumber tests for my java project.
My tests are working just fine, but there is a small warning appearing in my .feature file.

Below, I am passing an integer from the .feature file into my Step Definitions in a seperate java class

A yellow squiggly line appears under the below step in my .feature file:

```
Then the status code should be <StatusCode>
```

The warning message I receive is:

> No definition found for `the status code should be`

Here is my feature file examples table:

```
| StatusCode |
| 200        |
```

And below is my Step Definition:

```
@Then("^the status code should be (\\d+)$")
```

This error is preventing me from *Ctrl + Clicking* the '*Then*' statement to bring me to the above Step Definition in my java class.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what may be going wrong?

Maybe this isn't the way you should be passing an integer through an examples table

Comment: All other steps definition are working fine?

Comment: @LunaticJape Hi - Yep, I'm able to Ctrl + click into other step definitions from the .feature file. It's really strange

Comment: What's your method under `@Then`?

Answer (score 0):

The regexp to match the step method must match the text in the step (literally).

If your step is

```
Then the status code should be <StatusCode>
```

the regexp in your glue code

```
@Then("^the status code should be (\\d+)$")
```

would not match (hence you cannot CTRL+click it) the `StatusCode`.

Following simple example would work.

```
Scenario Outline: outline
  Given something
  Then the status code should be <StatusCode>
  Examples:
    | StatusCode |
    | 200        |
```

and the linked step definition

```
@Then("^the status code should be ([^\"]*)$")
public void theStatusCodeShouldBe(String statusCode) throws Throwable {
    ...
}
```

**edit** If you want to pass the status code as `Integer` you might change the signature of the step definition as

```
@Then("^the status code should be ([^\"]*)$")
public void theStatusCodeShouldBe(Integer statusCode) throws Throwable {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @user9847788 You might change the signature of the step definition. Have a look in the added example.